# How to resolve a Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException with foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a C# project with Microsoft SQL Server as the database. I've written an ALTER TABLE statement to make some changes to a table in my database. However, when I try to execute this statement, I encounter the following error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_SampleTable_ReferenceTable_ReferenceColumn". The conflict occurred in database "MyDatabase", table "dbo.ReferenceTable"

It appears that the error is caused by an existing foreign key constraint in my table. I've double-checked the ALTER TABLE statement, and it seems correct. How can I resolve this issue and successfully complete the table modification operation?

Here's the ALTER TABLE statement I'm trying to execute:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SampleTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SampleTable_ReferenceTable_ReferenceColumn
        FOREIGN KEY (ReferenceColumn) REFERENCES dbo.ReferenceTable (Id);
```

Any suggestions or guidance on how to address this situation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry, looks like you try to add two constraints with the same name.

Comment: Could be you tried to run this statement 2 times. It could also be that you reused the same name on accident somewhere else in your schema.

Comment: Do all ids in SampleTable exist in ReferenceTable?

Comment: `FK_SampleTable_ReferenceTable_ReferenceColumn` <-- is this the real name?. Id NOT, then, is the name of constraint in the error and the name of constraint in the `Alter table` are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should issue the command ALTER TABLE twice: the first time to remove the CONSTRAINT (if exists), the second to ADD it again:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SampleTable
    DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS FK_SampleTable_ReferenceTable_ReferenceColumn;

ALTER TABLE dbo.SampleTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SampleTable_ReferenceTable_ReferenceColumn
        FOREIGN KEY (ReferenceColumn) REFERENCES dbo.ReferenceTable (Id);
```